# Scalding tutorial: com.twitter.scalding.InvalidSourceException: Data is missing from one or more paths

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

With Hadoop 2.2 installed on single node  I try to run Scalding tutorial, part 1, with command:

```
$ yarn jar target/scalding-tutorial-0.8.11.jar Tutorial0 --hdfs
```

https://github.com/Cascading/scalding-tutorial/

Before running tutorial I Have copied required file `hello.txt` to HDFS:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /data
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2014-02-04 16:35 /data/10gsort
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs         26 2014-07-03 15:07 /data/hello.txt
```

It looks like tutorial can not find input file:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.twitter.scalding.InvalidSourceException:[TextLine(data/hello.txt)] Data is missing from one or more paths in: List(data/hello.txt)
at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource.validateTaps(FileSource.scala:102)
at com.twitter.scalding.Job$$anonfun$validateSources$1.apply(Job.scala:158)
at com.twitter.scalding.Job$$anonfun$validateSources$1.apply(Job.scala:153)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at com.twitter.scalding.Job.validateSources(Job.scala:153)
at com.twitter.scalding.Job.buildFlow(Job.scala:91)
at com.twitter.scalding.Job.run(Job.scala:126)
at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.start$1(Tool.scala:109)
at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:125)
at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at JobRunner$.main(JobRunner.scala:27)
at JobRunner.main(JobRunner.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Looks like it's looking for `data/hello.txt` and not `/data/hello.txt`, may it be the case ?

Comment: Yes, it looks to me the same also. But how can I fix this? Every tutorial program works both in a `local` and `hdfs` mode. When `--hdfs` arguement is given tutorial code ` hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(new hadoop.conf.Configuration, new Tool, args);` should take care of converting the argument `data/hello.txt` to `/data/hello.txt` appropriately. But it does not.

Comment: In fact, `data/hello.txt` and `/data/hello.txt` are not the same. Are you familiar with relative and absolute path ?

Comment: Yes, I am. Scalding also comes with a ruby script `scald.rb` to run Scalding jobs. It allows switching from local development to hadoop mode using a single switch. That means converting arguments path from local to hdfs path, such as `data/hello.txt` to `/data/hello.txt`, I assume. But I don't see where tutorial runs this script ...

Answer (score 0):

TextLine turns out to build a Hadoop Path according to the given path and configuration.

[Hadoop Path API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) shows "A path string is absolute if it begins with a slash."

Tutorial I fixes the input to be "data/hello.txt", which actually ends up with a relative path. Current working directory will be prepended to form an absolute and solid path.